# Как сделать объёмную круговую диаграмму для сайта?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Есть задумка на сайт сделать круговую диаграмму как на изображении.

[image: Диаграмма]

Нужно чтобы в центре был вырез, а при наведении сегмент выезжал. Предполагаю, что лучше это дело реализовать на Three.js. Попытался, но получилось только сделать слитную форму без сегментов. И то круг получился сегментированный (угловатый), что не удалось исправить.

Как вообще можно реализовать эту идею (как сделать этот "квадратный тор" и разбить на сегменты)?

Comment: HighCharts 3D Pie подойдет? (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12725)

Comment: @Kromster, спасибо большое! Подойдет :)

Comment: _"Как вообще можно реализовать эту идею (как сделать этот "квадратный тор" и разбить на сегменты)?"_ Растягивать/сгибать/деформировать боксы/кубы либо в js, либо в шейдерах :)